# What type of data that is separated by \ and is in hex?

Tags: python

I have a data set that is pulled from a pixhawk. I am trying to parse this data and plot some of them vs time. The issue is when I use this code to open one of the bin files:

```
with open("px4log.bin", "rb") as binary_file:
    # Read the whole file at once
    data = binary_file.read()
    print(data)
```

I get data that looks like this:

```
b'\xa3\x95\x80\x80YFMT\x00BBnNZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Type,Length,Name,Format,Columns\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa3\x95\x80\x81\x17PARMNf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Name,Value\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa3\x95\x80\x82-GPS\x00BIHBcLLeeEefI\x00\x00\x00Status,TimeMS,Week,NSats,HDop,Lat,Lng,RelAlt,Alt,Spd,GCrs,VZ,T\x00\x00\xa3\x95\x80\x83\x1fIMU\x00Iffffff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00TimeMS,GyrX,GyrY,GyrZ,AccX,AccY,AccZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
```

I was told it is supposed to be in binary, but it's not. Unless python is doing something to the data set when it is opening it?

You can download this sample data set if you would from:

```
https://pixhawk.org/_media/downloads/px4log_sample_1.px4log.zip
```

Comment: *"`'b'` appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode: now the data is read and written in the form of bytes objects."* [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: To which your next question would be "but what am I supposed to do with these bytes?", and the answer would be [you unpack them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

Comment: @CoryKramer Do I know know the location of each byte? Like is there a key for how the data is structured? or I don't need to know that?

Comment: the phrase "binary" usually means "non-text" - of course *everything* is binary in the end.  The `b'` prefix means that this is a byte-object, the bytes are displayed as best they can, in hexadecimal when they don't map to single byte characters.  Why do you say it is not binary?  The `\x00` termination bytes looks like it has come from C.

Comment: \xNN is hex code. The rest are just ASCII. This looks like some data structure being serialized.

Comment: @cdarke So is it possible to read this data into an array and do data manipulation on it without knowing anything else like a key to how the binary is structured?

Comment: Did you check this? http://dev.px4.io/advanced-ulog-file-format.html

Comment: and this one:  https://github.com/PX4/Firmware/blob/master/Tools/sdlog2/sdlog2_dump.py

Comment: @j.Jones:  you need to know how the binary is formatted.  For example, you have no idea is "x\2a" is the number 42,  the character "*", or should be combined with the previous or next byte to make a larger number.  You probably need `struct.unpack()` to unpack it from C into python.  See the program I gave a link to above .

Comment: @Ashalynd Thanks, I didn't see that one before. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @cdarke Yes I knew about the sdlog2_dump, however, I was trying as a learning experience to parse it myself without converting.

Comment: @Ashalynd Sorry I am very new to python, the site you linked codes doesn't work in python 3.5. Is this supposed to be Python 2.7?

Comment: You picked a difficult one to learn with!  Writing the program is actually the easy part, the most difficult is understanding the data and that is the part that needs the most work here.  You have to understand the data *before* writing a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Python is showing you the binary data represented in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) when the characters do not correspond with a regular [ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character. For example `\xa3` is a byte of hexidecimal value `A3` which is `10100011` in binary. `T` on the other hand could be printed as `\x54` which is a byte of binary value `01010100`. Since you used the `print` function, python assumes you are trying to convert the binary data to a human readable string, so instead of `\x54` it showed the corresponding character `T`.

You can use the following code to get an array of binary strings that represent your data:

```
data = '\xa3\x95\x80\x80YFMT\x00BBnNZ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Type,Length,Name,Format,Columns'

decimalArray = map(ord,data)
byteArray = map(lambda x: "{0:b}".format(x), decimalArray)
print byteArray
```

Here is the output:

```
['10100011', '10010101', '10000000', '10000000', '1011001', '1000110', '1001101', '1010100', '0', '1000010', '1000010', '1101110', '1001110', '1011010', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1010100', '1111001', '1110000', '1100101', '101100', '1001100', '1100101', '1101110', '1100111', '1110100', '1101000', '101100', '1001110', '1100001', '1101101', '1100101', '101100', '1000110', '1101111', '1110010', '1101101', '1100001', '1110100', '101100', '1000011', '1101111', '1101100', '1110101', '1101101', '1101110', '1110011']
```

Comment: I see, but doesn't this kind of make the data harder to parse?

Comment: @J.Jones: Alden is trying to explain something to you, not show you a way of setting about parsing the data.

Comment: @BillBell Gotcha, so it is just the way python is reading. What I still don't understand from the other comments is, how do I tell python what the data structure is. I tried reading on unpack.struct but it am hitting a brick wall trying to do this.

Comment: @J.Jones: Ah, you have to tell us something first! At least those of us that no nothing about pixhawk. What's the structure of the data that it produces? If you can give us that then someone here can probably tell you how to throw up a Python structure to match it.

Comment: @J.Jones I suggest creating a new question for that issue since this one only asks about the hex representation in the printed string.

Comment: @Alden I posted the question, and tried to provide as much information as I have. Thanks again for helping, I have been stuck on this for a week now.

Comment: @BillBell I posted the question, and tried to provide as much information as I have. Thanks again for helping, I have been stuck on this for a week now